# What is this yellow circled component?

Tags: circuit-design, power-electronics, components, identification, electrical

[image]

I'm designing a circuit for lightning detection. I want to know what is this component. CNT1

Comment: Where did you find this image... give us more information

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it might be a [counter module](http://www.conrad.com/ce/en/overview/1114010/Counters) from [Conrad](http://www.conrad.com/ce/en/content/cms_au_company/Unternehmen?WT.ac=footer_company)

Though that part number seems obsolete. But you could always ask them.

Perhaps [something like this one](http://www.conrad.com/ce/en/product/126684/VOLTCRAFT-DCM-240-Counter-module-DCM-240-Assembly-dimensions-45-x-22-mm?ref=list).

[image]